# Redirect to different pages for request coming from subdomain site

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have main site and its subdomain site.

- When user is entering main site url `www.mysite.com` it should get redirected to `'Login.aspx'`
- When user is entering sub domain site url `sample.mysite.com` it should get redirected to `'Welcom.aspx'`

To achieve this what is the best way to do ?

- Changes in IIS settings ?
- Modify Code in `Global.asax`
- Create Dummy Page for redirection

What code i have to wrote if i required to modify global.asax ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I will choose 2nd option, modify the Global.asax file.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower();
        if (host == "www.mysite.com")
        {
            //Incase if you are using any session
            if (Session["User"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            else
            {
                //validate the session
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }
        }
        else if (host == "sample.mysite.com")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Application_BeginRequest` fires only once, not on every request

Comment: This event raised at the start of **every request** for the web application.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the redirection , modify the code in global.asax will be the best one